# Lambda to extract some integers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

```
List<int[]> A = ServiceItems.First()
.ServiceItemDetails.Select(x => new int[]{ x.Numbers}).ToList();
```

This gets me a list of integer arrays.

I need a list of plain integers

I tried this:

```
List<int> A = ServiceItems.First()
.ServiceItemDetails.Select(x => new int{ x.Numbers})
.ToList();
```

Ouch!

> Cannot initialize type int with a collection....does not implement IEnumerable

How do I accomplish this and what exactly is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `x.Numbers`? A single integer?

Comment: @JonSkeet just an int

Comment: Given that that's counterintuitive, it would have been worth saying so to start with.

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but I'm not particularly surprised other people did, given the information you missed out. Next time, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just take out the array part?

```
List<int> A = ServiceItems.First().
    ServiceItemDetails.Select(x => x.Numbers).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear as you haven't told us what `x.Numbers` is, but if the first code really gives you a `List<int[]>` then it may be as simple as:

```
List<int> A = ServiceItems.First()
                          .ServiceItemDetails
                          .Select(x => x.Numbers)
                          .ToList();
```

If that's the case, and `x.Numbers` really *is* a single `int`, you'd be well advised to rename it if you can - it currently *sounds* like a collection of numbers.

Comment: Note how aligning the code to a single call per line also makes it easier to read - particularly here on Stack Overflow, where horizontal space is at a premium. (No-one likes scrolling horizontally.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<int> A = ServiceItems.First().ServiceItemDetails.SelectMany(x => x.Numbers).ToList();
```

[SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) behaves like Select() but has the effect of "flattening" the resulting collection of collection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to flatten the list of arrays of integers into one big list of integers?  Without any additional sorting/filtering/etc. you can use `.SelectMany()`.  Something like this:

```
var integers = ServiceItems.First().ServiceItemDetails.SelectMany(s => s.Numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a SelectMany to flatten your list of integers like so...

```
List<int[]> A = ServiceItems.First().ServiceItemDetails.SelectMany(x => x.Numbers).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int[]> A = ServiceItems.First().ServiceItemDetails.Select(x => x.Numbers).ToList();
```

You need not initialize int as you would initialize class by doing `new int{...}`. `int` is a value type to which, you can assign the value directly.